# How to implement horizontal horizontal scaling with mutii-topic failover subscriptions in Pulsar

Tags: node.js, apache-pulsar

I have about 100 entities, each with the same set of topics associated with them (e.g A-foo, B-foo, A-bar, B-bar) on a Pulsar message bus. For a given entity/topic, I need to process messages in the order they're produced, but ordering between different entities doesn't matter. The number of consumers will adjust dynamically, so I was hoping to rely on Pulsar to automatically allocate messages to consumers proportionally, guaranteeing ordering. I'm using the Node.js pulsar client.

Looking at the Pulsar documentation

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/concepts-messaging/#failover--non-partitioned-topics

it seems like using failover mode with multiple topics should automatically allocate between multiple consumers, while ensuring ordering within a topic since each topic is going to be allocated to a single consumer. However, what I'm seeing is that all topics are being allocated to whichever consumer starts up first, rather than being reallocated dynamically. I've tried setting a consumer name with a pseudo-random UUID to see if that's required, and I've also tried subscribing to all topics as both a list of topics and as a Regex pattern.

Using a shared subscription does successfully send messages to all consumers, but as expected this loses the benefit of guaranteed ordering within a specific topic.